# Testing In App billing from Google

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am testing the in App products from Google. I have purchased the product which can be bought only once in the App. It works fine. but to test various scenarios I have to reset or make it consumed.

Is there is any way to consume it manually ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I temporarily made a button in my purchase `AlertDialog` for "Consume". Here's the code snippet:

```
        /*builder.setNeutralButton("Consume Purchase", new Dialog.OnClickListener() {//For testing.


        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            consumePurchase();

        }
    });*/
```

You need an instance of `IabHelper`, of course, to get the `consumePurchase()` command.

More info in the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume).

Comment: Anything we can do outside the App

Answer (score 0):

Go into the google wallet merchant account and cancel the purchase. It takes 10-20 minutes to reset but it will.

Comment: i waited for more than 30 min. it was not successfull. I finally tried mHelper.consumeAsync